# Create and Update 2 CPT sequentially

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to create + update a CPT after a post have been created sequentially in the same flow?

For example:

First: I do a wp_insert_post($my_first_cpt) (with some data, and it's executed on save_post hook)

Second: wp_update_post($my_second_cpt) (with DATA from $my_first_cpt, for example a random seed) and show be executed inmediately after

So essentially $my_first_cpt has to be created and stored and inmediately afterwards, something has to fire to get data from $my_first_post and update $my_second_post

Is this possible?
I've tried to put one after another and it doesn't simply work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, which I'm not liking much, but it works

Essentially what I do is create two hooks to save_post (in this case this is the action that launches this script) with different priorities for example 10 and 20
In the priority 10 I put the wp_insert_post
And in the priority 20 I put the wp_update_post

It works, but is doesn't seem to be the best solution...